# Cloud Tasks: Unable to create with a queue in europe-west2 with cli

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When using the node library `@google-cloud/tasks` and trying to create a Cloud Tasks Queue in the `europe-west2` region with the `client.createQueue` function I get the following error:

```
Any resource that needs App Engine can only be created/updated in the App Engine region. Location must equal europe-west1 because the App Engine app that is associated with this project is located in europe-west1
```

As far as I can tell App Engine can only be set to `europe-west` which is considered to be `europe-west1`. However I can create a queue in `europe-west2` through the Cloud Console. For regulation reasons we need to keep data inside the UK so preferably we wouldn't use `europe-west1`

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose `europe-west2` when creating the App Engine instance, I just tested in a new project.
If you already created a `europe-west` instance then Google don't let you change the region once it's created, see [3rd paragraph here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations). Unfortunately you can't delete the App Engine instance either without deleting the whole project.
The only way to change an App Engine region is to delete the whole project, recreate and choose the new region.